# How to use mask images for icons in fixed footer?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here is my footer:

```html
<div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nearby" data-icon="nearby">Nearby</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my custom icon using a mask image:

```
.ui-icon-nearby {-webkit-mask-image: url(../i/nearby.png); -moz-mask-image: url(../i/nearby.png); background-color: #ffffff}
```

I get a white square on the Nearby item in the navbar, no icon...

BUT if I add `data-visible-on-page-show="false"` in the footer div, I see the icon but the footer is not fixed anymore, it goes at the bottom of the page...

Thanks!

Comment: If you create a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue it would be helpful.